How to scale down a 1D array of N elements like scaling an image to desired length
I have a normalized (-1.0, 1.0) 1D numpy float32 array with N (min=320, max=1600) number of elements.
I would like to reduce it to 160 elements the same way an image is reduced. It's like scaling down
an image of (N, 1) size to (160, 1). Can't use PIL because of negative values and secondly it would be overkill to use it. Example
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

If I have to reduce it 5 elements than one simpler way is to delete elements but I am sure image scaling work differently. There will be deletion but I think scaling process adjust near by values to make image still look similar.

You can try with scipy.signal.resample.
